# Calling upon a method to change textbox value

Tags: c#

I have a method called BuyShares() that is supposed to take a value in a textbox and add another user input value to it.  I would like to use a messagebox that sets off the method by the user clicking okay.  The only problem is that I can't seem to call upon the method. 
This is the method.

```
public void BuyShares(int anAmount)
    {
        int newShares;
        newShares = GetInvestmentShare() - anAmount;
        SetInvestmentShare(newShares);
    }
```

And this is the messagebox I have set up

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Your transaction is complete", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        if(result==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtStockSharesTab3.Text=??????
    }
```

This is a windows form application and the program has several different classes

Comment: What is `txtStockSharesTab3.Text` supposed to be?

Comment: txtStockSharesTab3.Text is the textbox with the value that is having the new value added to it.  It is the textbox that's value will change

Answer (score 0):

Without giving away the answer because you probably want to learn something from this...

I'm guessing you want to get the amount of shares to buy from one textbox, then call `BuyShares` and finally update `txtStockSharesTab3` to this value.

Your `BuyShares` method returns `void` meaning it won't return a value.  Somewhere in that method is where you're going to update your `txtStockSharesTab3` textbox.  Is that exact method signature for `BuyShares` required?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "signature"?

Comment: The signature is a the definition of what the method receives and what it returns.  For example : `public void BuyShares(int anAmount)
` is different than `public int BuyShares(int anAmount)
`

Comment: No it is not required. Would setting it up as "public int" work?

Comment: When I set it up as "public int BuyShares(int anAmount)" I get an error under BuyShares saying not all code paths return a value

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean change it to that.  I'd recommend you read up on how to properly write methods.